# use more than 30 arguments in sum function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I want to use more than 30 arguments in sum formula for excel, I am using below formula:-

```
=SUM(IF(AND(ISNUMBER($F$73),ISNUMBER($J$73)),PRODUCT($F$73,$J$73/100),0),IF(AND(ISNUMBER($G$74),ISNUMBER($J$74)),PRODUCT($G$74,$J$74),0))
```

Above formula will work fine for 30 argumnets, but for more than  30 argumemts excel will return error(`#VALUE`)

Comment: Tell us what you intend to do instead of showing a non-working formula.

Comment: Is there is any pattern to your conditions? eg F73,G74,H75,... and J73,J74,J75,... If so there will likely be a more compact formula and if not you probably want to modify the setup so that there is some kind of order as using long formulas can introduce errors and is not recommended practice.

Comment: there s no specific pattern for the conditions,I am exporting report to excel and creating this formulla through programming,based upon each cell value.

Comment: why programatically creating an unlimitted-length formula instead of computing the results onchange?

Answer (score 0):

You could batch smaller groups into sub-SUMs like this:
`=SUM(SUM(1,2), SUM(3,4),...)`.

Comment: I tried this but after that I am getting error that "Formula is too long"

Comment: Define Names for subformulae. Then use =SUM on the Names.

Comment: for defining name to subformula, i have to put each subformula in different cell and then use all these defined names in one formula, but i want my whole formula in one cell.

Comment: a named range can consist of any number of cells - they do not need to be adjacent

Comment: A Name need not refer to a range only. If can be any formula, e.g. you could define the name MYNAME to be =SUM(A1,B2,C3,D4).

Answer (score 0):

This version will be shorter, you can add as many as you want, only limit will be maximum formula length

`=(COUNT(F73,J73)=2)*(F73*J73/100)+(COUNT(G74,J74)=2)*(G74*J74/100)`

Comment: yes now i am facing the maximum formula lenght issue, can you suggest how to deal with this error

Comment: I am creating this formulla through programming, so there is no limit. But currently I am trying upto 100 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could save further characters in your formula like this:

```
=(N(F73)*N(J73)+N(G74)*N(J74))/100
```

which could be extended much further, but for clarity, I'd suggest writing a custom UDF:

```
=SPRange((F73,G74),(J73,J74))%
```

SPRange would work like SUMPRODUCT but operates on multiple ranges:

```
Function SPRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Double

Dim i As Long, n As Long, rng As Range, Arr() As Double

n = Range1.Count
ReDim Arr(1 To n) As Double

i = 1
For Each rng In Range1
    If IsNumeric(rng.Value2) Then Arr(i) = rng.Value2
    i = i + 1
Next rng

i = 1
SPRange = 0
For Each rng In Range2
    If IsNumeric(rng.Value2) Then SPRange = SPRange + Arr(i) * rng.Value2
    i = i + 1
Next rng

End Function
```

If you want to extend to many ranges you can define names through code:

```
names.Add "Range1",Range("f73,g74")
names.Add "Range2",Range("j73,j74")
```

which allows for over 1000 cells in my tests. Then just enter the formula as:

```
=SPRange(Range1,Range2)%
```