# Python xlwt: sum function max arguments limit?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I encountered this error while generating excel file with xlwt library:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormula.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.__parser.formula()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 81, in formula
    self.expr("V")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 88, in expr
    self.prec0_expr(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 133, in prec0_expr
    self.prec1_expr(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 151, in prec1_expr
    self.prec2_expr(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 181, in prec2_expr
    self.prec3_expr(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 210, in prec3_expr
    self.prec4_expr(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 228, in prec4_expr
    self.prec5_expr(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 251, in prec5_expr
    self.primary(arg_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/ExcelFormulaParser.py", line 517, in primary
    raise Exception("%d parameters for function: %s" % (arg_count, func_tok.text))
Exception: 185 parameters for function: sum
```

Digging source code on `xlwt`, I can see that there is hard limit of maximum 30 arguments on `sum` function. I wonder why there is such limit? If there are some implications if it would be bigger?

My implementation of `xlwt` excel files generation uses sum and with lots of data it can use much more arguments than 30 (because it sums many sub sections of a file).

Limitations are set here:

`xlwt/ExcelMagic.py`:

```
all_funcs_by_name = {
    # Includes Analysis ToolPak aka ATP aka add-in aka xcall functions,
    # distinguished by -ve opcode.
    # name: (opcode, min # args, max # args, func return type, func arg types)
    # + in func arg types means more of the same.
...
'SUM'         : (  4, 1, 30, 'V', 'D+'),
...
}
```

Third number (30) means maximum arguments for function `sum`.

Does anyone know if there is some kind of workaround so I could use any number of arguments if needed or for some reason it is not OK?

P.S. I can potentially use any number of arguments directly on `excel` or `calc` when using `sum` function (at least did not reach that limit if there is any, by testing)

Comment: How about using nested `SUM`s? `SUM(SUM(1,2,...,30),SUM(31,32,...))`.

Comment: @Rawing I was actually just thinking about this after I have written a question. I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

xlwt is merely enforcing *Excel's* argument limit for the `SUM` function in .xls files. Actually, this is the absolute maximum for any Excel function, not just `SUM`. If xlwt were to allow more than 30, then the workbook it generated would be invalid according to Excel itself.

Some workarounds are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992571/use-more-than-30-arguments-in-sum-function-in-excel) and [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/72870-How-do-I-overcome-SUM-s-30-reference-limit-(Excel-2002-SP3)).

Note that the 30-argument limitation is for an old version of Excel. Using a [more recent version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) increases the limit to 255. To generate newer Excel workbooks, use [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) instead of xlwt. See [this table](https://www.itlektor.cz/en/microsoft-excel/excel-limits-specifications/) comparing the limits of Excel 2003 (.xls) versus 2010 (.xlsx).